# Mongo as replica set in Testcontainers in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, docker, testcontainers

I am trying to run Mongo in Docker by using [Testcontainers](https://testcontainers.com/modules/mongodb/) in dotnet. I don't have any issue when I use following code:

```
        Container = new MongoDbBuilder()
            .WithPortBinding("27017")
            .Build();
```

But with this default *MongoDbBuilder* I can not run it as replica set. I found I have to run it as container builder with custom image:

```
        Container = new ContainerBuilder()
            .WithImage("mongo:6.0")
            .WithEntrypoint("mongod")
            .WithCommand("--replSet", "rs0")
            .WithPortBinding("27017")
            .Build();
```

Then I init replica set as:

```
    var result = Container.ExecAsync(new List<string>
    {
        "mongosh", "--eval", "rs.initiate()"
    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

When I try to do any operation with mongo in dotnet code, I get timeout error. When I run it in debug mode and try to connect to created docker by Mongo client (I use DataGrip), I get timeout error too. When I connect directly in docker container console by *mongosh* it works.

Docker running image:

[image]

Connection settings in Mongo client:

[image]

When I use MongoDbBuilder, as mentioned at the beginning, the Mongo client with connection string works.

Comment: what output in the code here `Then I init replica set as:`? What connection string you use in the .net code? Provide a full error

Comment: I know that it doesn't help out-of-the-box. But you can look at other testcontainers modules implementations, for example tc-java MongoDb module is pretty advanced - https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/main/modules/mongodb/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/MongoDBContainer.java 
can do replica set, sharding, and so on. And if you're good with .NET it might be fairly straightforward to port, maybe even submit the implementation back too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving `mongod` to command worked for me:

```cs
var container = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage("mongo:6.0")
        .WithCommand("mongod", "--replSet", "rs0")
        .WithPortBinding("27017")
        .Build();
```

Do not forget to switch to "No auth" since default docker image setup does not require auth (unlike the one created by `MongoDbBuilder`):

> By default Mongo's configuration requires no authentication for access, even for the administrative user.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this answer here for future me:

I was able to use MongoDbBuilder to get a single node replica set working with the following which allows me to use transactions:

```
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        mongoContainer = new MongoDbBuilder()
            .WithUsername("")
            .WithPassword("")
            .WithImage("mongo:latest")
            .WithExtraHost("host.docker.internal", "host-gateway")
            .WithCommand("--replSet", "rs0")
            .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer())
            .Build();

        await mongoContainer.StartAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        await mongoContainer.ExecScriptAsync($"rs.initiate({{_id:'rs0',members:[{{_id:0,host:'host.docker.internal:{mongoContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(27017)}'}}]}})", cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        var connectionString = mongoContainer.GetConnectionString();
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
```

Using an empty string for `.WithUserName("")` and `.WithPassword("")` seems to be equivalent to "No Auth".  I think `.WithUserName(null)` and `.WithPassword(null)` works as well.

> Important: Make sure your hosts file (on host machine) has the entry `127.0.0.1 host.docker.internal`